# How to use .htaccess file in php over localhost

Tags: php

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^locations/msu/admin/login(/.*)?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

i am changing httpd.conf file line no.264 and line no.130 but it not works properly.
**xampp server**
line No:-264 :AllowOverride All and line No:-130 LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config. remove # in **httpd.conf file**.

Comment: what are you using XAMPP?

Comment: and explain in a better manner please, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: make sure you enabled mod_rewrite apache module

Comment: "httpd.conf file line no.264 and line no.130" ? whats on those lines, maybe you could add that to your question, we don't know all files by the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you want to rewrite URL's. There are few things you need to make sure:

1. Ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. For XAMPP, it should be enabled by default.
2. Set `AllowOverride None` in the file, `httpd.conf`.
3. Lastly, make sure to restart the server